# Build OpenCV with CUDA 12, undefined identifiers cudaUnbindTexture, textureReference

Tags: opencv, cmake, cuda

I try to compile Opencv with cuda, but I have an error

Running with:

- nvidia-driver-525.60.13
- CUDA 12.0
- OpenCV 3.4.16

I don't know where it comes from...

```bash
[  7%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.cc.o
/home/totar/cv2/opencv-3.4.16/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/ptr2d/texture.hpp(61): error: texture is not a template

/home/totar/cv2/opencv-3.4.16/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/ptr2d/texture.hpp(83): error: identifier "cudaUnbindTexture" is undefined

/home/totar/cv2/opencv-3.4.16/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cuda/common.hpp(99): error: identifier "textureReference" is undefined

3 errors detected in the compilation of "/home/totar/cv2/opencv-3.4.16/modules/core/src/cuda/gpu_mat.cu".
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o.Release.cmake:279 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/totar/cv2/opencv-3.4.16/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o


modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_1_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1889: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Output of nvcc --version

```bash
totar@totar:~/cv2/opencv-3.4.16/build$ nvcc --version

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_24_19:12:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.76
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.31968024_0
```

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for represent textual information. Instead, paste the error log as **text**. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: Don’t use CUDA 12, use a CUDA 11 or earlier release, the functions in question have been removed in the CUDA 12 release

Comment: Please post an answer detailing your solution

Comment: and consider using a newer version of OpenCV than v3.x because that is nearing the end of its support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CUDA 12.0 [dropped support](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-12-0-still-support-for-texture-reference-support-for-pascal-architecture-warp-synchronous-programming/237284/1) for legacy texture references.  Therefore, any code that uses legacy texture references can no longer be properly compiled with CUDA 12.0 or beyond.

Legacy texture reference usage has been deprecated for some time now.

As indicated in the comments, by reverting to CUDA 11.x where legacy texture references are still supported (albeit deprecated) you won't run into this issue.

The other option may happen some day when OpenCV converts usage of legacy texture references to [texture object methods](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/).  In that case, it may then be possible to use CUDA 12.0 or a newer CUDA toolkit to compile OpenCV/CUDA functionality.

There is no work around to somehow allow texture reference usage to be compiled properly with CUDA 12.0 and beyond.

Likewise, this limitation is not unique or specific to OpenCV.  Any CUDA code that uses texture references can no longer be compiled properly with CUDA 12.0 and beyond.  The options are to refactor that code with texture object usage instead, or revert to a previous CUDA toolkit that still has the deprecated support for texture reference usage.

Comment: I had the same problem as the original post. I am on fedora and for some reason can't get down to cuda-11.8. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Following from Robert Crovella's answer, another solution (for many people) would be to build OpenCV-4x instead, where the backend uses OpenCL for GPU access, and the Cuda modules are optional (found in the separate https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib repository).

Obviously this depends on whether you have a lot of code using the Cuda gpuMat class, which you would need to migrate to the UMat class for the OpenCV-4 "Transparent API" (aka TAPI). This probably worth doing for code that you intend to keep using for the long term.